Unable to get response from APIGateway through react app
Calling the api from postman gives the expected output without any errors. But while trying to make request from react app cors related error in showing up.
PS:- this is error i am getting. "Access to fetch at 'aws-api-end-point' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
I have deployed an api in AWS ApiGateway. Also integrated a lambda function. The api request works all fine while making the request from postman but while trying to make the same request from React Application i am getting cors error.

That's a common issue with the API gateway, basically you just need to enable CORS. with lambda it works fine but when accessed from a browser-based application like React you need to enable CORS beforehand. The error indicates that the browser is enforcing CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policies.
you can find all the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html
